# How can I get position of text that is shifted down in a RichTextBox due to larger text on the same line?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

There was a point where I was using `GetPositionFromCharIndex()` to get the location of the start of a particular string in my `RichTextBox`. Due to other requirements, I made a change to increase the font size of some words. If a word happens to get enlarged (and the string whose position I want remains the same), the string I'm measuring gets pushed down but the Y position reads as being the same for some reason.

I wrote a quick test app to verify this and can replicate it. Below is all of the code I am using (apart from the designer of course).

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    richTextBox1.Text = "Test statement";

    //Select "Test" and increase the size
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("Test");
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 4;
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, 16);

    Point test = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("Test"));
    Point statement = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("statement"));

    //"statement" is pushed down due to "Test" being enlarged,
    //Yet the Y value is the same for both words
    label1.Text = $"Test location: {test.X},{test.Y}";
    label2.Text = $"statement location: {statement.X},{statement.Y}";
}
```

And a screenshot of the results:
[image: String position measure results]

Is this something I can get around? Clearly the word "statement" doesn't *truly* have the same Y value. Seems like as far as the `RichTextBox` is concerned, the word does start up that high so it just measures that, but if that is the case, there doesn't  seem to be an obvious solution to me.

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain what the problem is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @mjwills - I record the bounds of certain words, and in a hover event I check those bounds. If the cursor is over those bounds I want the word to appear clickable (aka, change the Cursor to the Hand). So in my example, if "statement" should be a clickable word, it looks kinda funny if I hover above it and still get the hand.

Answer (score 1):

`GetPositionFromCharIndex` is working [as designed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getpositionfromcharindex(v=vs.110).aspx).

The docs state:

> This method enables you to determine where in the control a specific
>   character index is located. You can use this method for such tasks as
>   displaying shortcut menu items or help information for a word in the
>   control. For example, if you wanted to display a menu of options to
>   the user when the user right clicks on a word in the control, you can
>   use this method to determine the position of the word to properly
>   display a ContextMenu control.

Given that, it makes sense for both words to return the same Y value - since you would expect right-click to act consistently for both words (so even if you right click slightly above the *statement* word it could still work as expected).

Comment: Whelp.... guess I can always try to measure the font sizes and change my Y based on that or something...